# Active executors on one spark partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, scalability

Is there any possibility that multiples executor of the same node work on the same partition, for example during a reduceByKey working on spark 1.6.2.

I have results that i don't understand. After the reduceByKey when i look the keys, the same appear multiple time, as many as the number of executor per node i suppose. Moreover when i kill one of the two slaves i note the same result.
There are the same key 2 times, i presume it's due to the number of executor per node which is by default set to 2.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).map(x=>(x%5,x))
val rrdd = rdd.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

And i obtain

```
rrdd.count = 10
```

Rather than what i suppose which is

```
rrdd.count = 5
```

I tried this

```
val rdd2 = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(8))
val rrdd = rdd2.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

And that one

```
val rdd3 = rdd.reduceByKey(new HashPartitioner(8), _+_)
```

Without obtain what i want.

Of course i can decrease the number of executor to one, but we will loose in efficiency with more than 5cores by executor.

I tried code above on spark-shell localy it works like a charm but when it comes to go on a cluster it fails...

I'm suddenly wondering if a partition is to big, is she divided with other nodes which can be a good strategy depending the case, not mine obviously ;)

So i humbly ask your help to solve this little mystery.

Comment: Please collect and print the tuples so we can see the result?

Comment: I've got each key two times, that's what i get from this process

Comment: Of course, sorry I missed that in your question...

Comment: Do you see the same sort of behaviour if you do a groupbykey then a count?

Comment: I don't want use groupByKey, you have to avoid this behaviour as much as possible due to it's O(n²) cost... ReduceByKey is way more efficient ;)

Comment: Yep, just curious if you saw same behaviour

Comment: Also are the duplicated key/value pairs identical, both key and value? Please can you post the resulting tuples?  Any changes to spark configs? Are you on local machine / vm, or a cluster?